# How can I create a self-running DVD?

Tags: video, dvd, media-player, autorun

How can I make a DVD movie with its own player, means the disc has a DVD player that runs automatically when you put it in the computer?

Comment: Just put an `autorun.inf` file on the disk

Comment: Creating an `autorun.inf` file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/cc144206(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: take a look: http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-CD-and-DVD-Autoplay-in-Windows-XP

Comment: Is `autorun.inf` a Microsoft thing? Or does it work on all the other operating systems?

Comment: Why the vote-downs? Should we not be judging the quality of the question, and not whether we think the questioner is trying to do evil?

Comment: @richard: I have voted up, just do it too

Answer (score 1):

When a DVD or CD, etc is inserted into the computer, it's up to the operating system to decide what to do with it. If it is recognised as a DVD, then the computer might give you the option to play it using a media player (VLC, Windows Media Player, etc).

You can't force the DVD to run when it is inserted, but settings in the operating system can determine whether the disk is played automatically.

Comment: Good point, +1 :)

Comment: Nice answer. Just one more interpretation of the question. Let us say i have a new installation of Windows with no other programs like VLC installed. Should i have a portable version on VLC on my DVD (along with my movie), i can just click and play the DVD - Is this what the questioner is asking?        Should down-voting be "not anonymous" i think most users would think twice before down-voting. :-D